Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Chinese on topic here?
I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

Would you please translate the following paragraphs into Chinese?  

a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
  network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real.    Let's all press "commit" button!   

I need them to post about this proposal in facebook pages that
  are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
  facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
  more attention and so they might be seen by more people.


I'll give some pointers out so this post CAN be posted. 
Your post would have to show some type of effort to translate it yourself first. No, just copying and pasting into google translate it not enough because the chinese SE is not a free translating service.
The question might also have to be narrowed down a little, maybe separating the 5 bullet points. Stack Exchange is originally meant to be a place for people to find answers to the same questions they may have, this question however, is extremely personalized. An example question would be, "how would you translate definition phase in Chinese", and secretly throw in the third point allowing users to also correct any mistakes you made. (You can kind of see how ridiculous it is getting). 
Final point, if Chinese is your not main language, how would you know which answer is the best? By upvotes? By reputation? 
Translation is a tough business and requires a near native level of competency. To give you an example, I am a native English speaker, but studied in Taiwan for 8 years. I personally feel 8 years is still not enough to compensate for 12 years of mandatory education (elementary, middle, high school). I can translate from CH->ENG, but not ENG->CH. It also requires understanding of specific industry terms such as remote sensing and photogrammeetry. Hope this helps.

thanks a lot. I had the same question is spanish se and they advised me to ask in the chat room. Am I allowed to do the same in the italian chat room, providing my explanations in the comments of the above link?

Italian chat room? Im going to assume its a typo, or maybe you might be referring to all language chat rooms, and are coming at it from a localization stand point. Either way, personal advise is this, post it in the beta place because chat rooms discussions are non-existent, (at least in Chinese SE). I think even some "slight" effort will be good enough, if im speaking honestly. I have noticed recent trends in Chinese SE having a lot of native speakers coming on this site. This increases the level and ability, and im sure they will be willing to take the challenge.

A few unique and hard questions will surely be interesting, and worst case scenario, is that you get a few downvotes, Luckily, Chinese SE is one of the few places that are not down vote trigger happy if you know what I mean. >:) Hope this helps.

ok, yes that was a typo. in fact a copy and paste. so you advise me to do some efforts and then post in the main site. I'll try and I think I can just do a word by word translation through google translate. Because I'm completely illiterate in Chinese.

Translation questions need to have clear research effort on your part. However way you decide to show it, it must be there.
But also, your question needs to fit all the other SE standards: scoped (not too broad), narrow (not about too many things at once), and so on. Instead of asking how to translate a whole paragraph, you could ask how to overcome a certain point where you're stuck translating. 
That way, you could also ask multiple questions (possibly more reputation for you) and give the site more questions (better stats for us), while also increasing the quality.
